# Como actualizar la informacion de un archivo .txt en C#

Tags: c#

Buen día estimados tengo un pequeño inconveniente tengo esta rutina que me guarda un archivo encriptado en una ubicacion deseada, pero tengo este problema que cuando quiero sobreescribir el archivo lo que hace es volver a guardar la informacion con la que ya estaba duplicando la información, y lo que quiero saber que forma hay que hacer para que a la hora de sobreescribir al guardar no se duplique la información en el archivo

```
       private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos de texto (*.txt)|*.txt|Todos los 
             archivos(*.*)|*.*";
             if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
              {

                try
                {
                    //string contenido = "";
                    string linea = "";
                    using (StreamReader archivo = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                    {
                        string s = "";
                        while (archivo.Peek() > -1)
                        {
                            linea = archivo.ReadLine();
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linea))
                            {
                                //arch = linea;

                          using (StreamWriter file = 
                                    File.AppendText(saveFileDialog1.FileName))
                                {
                                    file.WriteLine(Encryption(linea));
                                    file.Close();

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    txtcaja1.Text = "";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al Guardar");
                }                
        }
    }
```

estoy utilizando esta linea para que sobreescriba pero lo que hace es que solo me agrega la ultima linea

```
            using (StreamWriter file = 
             
              new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName,false))
                                {
                                    file.WriteLine(Encryption(linea));
                                    file.Close();

                                }
```

y no se que es lo que me esta haciendo mal

Comment: Hola, aunque no es obligatorio, valora registrarte en la comunidad ya que obtendrás más beneficios de la misma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La información se duplica porque el método [`File.AppendText(saveFileDialog1.FileName)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-5.0), usado en el primer ejemplo, no sobreescribe el archivo sino que crea un `StreamWriter` que agrega texto al final de un archivo existente (sólo lo crea cuando no existe).

El problema se resuelve utilizando el [`StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName,false)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_) que nos muestras en el segundo ejemplo, pero hay que ubicarlo en otra parte. Donde lo tienes ubicado, soreescribe el archivo en cada iteración de `while` y es por eso que al final sólo obtienes la última línea.

La idea sería colocar el `StreamWriter` fuera del `while`, antes o después del `StreamReader`. Por ejemplo:

```
    private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Archivos de texto (*.txt)|*.txt|Todos los archivos(*.*)|*.*";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {                
            try
            {
                //string contenido = "";
                string linea = "";
                using (StreamReader archivo = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName))

                // | Ubica el StreamWriter en este punto fuera del while
                // V
                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName,false))
                {
                    string s = "";
                    while (archivo.Peek() > -1)
                    {
                        linea = archivo.ReadLine();
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linea))
                        {
                            file.WriteLine(Encryption(linea));

                            //NO cierres el StreamWriter aquí
                            //file.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                txtcaja1.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al Guardar");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me ha servido esa forma solo tengo una duda en que parte me sugieres colocar file.Close();

Comment: @ProgramadorJR. Cuando utilizas la instrucción [using](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) no es necesario colocar el `archivo.Close()` / `file.Close()` porque `using` se encarga de cerrarlo apropiadamente.

Comment: ahh entiendo. tu solucion me ha servido mucho.